# Java changing instance type to already created class type

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to Java and currently I'm learning constructor. So I have a `Person` class

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private double height;

    Person(String name, double height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

and a `Book` class

```
public class Book {

    private String author;
    private String title;

    public Raamat(String author, String title) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

and a `Test` class

```
public class TestBook {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book harryp = new Book("Rouling", "Harry Potter");
    }
}
```

My task is to change `Book` class, so that author is Person-type instead of String-type like this:

```
private String author  -->  private Person author
```

So the `Book` class will look like this:

```
public class Book {

    private Person author;
    private String title;

    public Book(String author, String title) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

So basically it should get author's name from `Person's` constructor? Or how does it work? And how should I modify `Test` class for it to work?

Comment: Your `Book` class's constructor is called `Raamat`, I'm guessing an editing error in the question?

Comment: what is Raamat?

Comment: (Side note: The author of the Harry Potter books is named *Rowling* [pronounced "rolling" in her case], not Rouling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
public class Book {
    private Person author;
    private String title;

    public Book(String author, String title) {
        this.author = new Person(author);
        this.title = title;
    }
}

class Person {

    private String name;
    private double height;
    public static final double DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 0.0;

    Person(String name, double height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }

    Person(String name) {
        this(name, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

You have to add one more constructor into your `Person` class, and instantate a new `Person` when you pass String `author` into `Book`

```
Book b = new Book("Mike", "Book Title");
```

Alternatively, pass `person` instance into Book and access name by `getName()`:

```
public class Book {
    private Person author;
    private String title;

    public Book(Person author, String title) {
        this.author = author.getName();
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to initialize the `Person` object first.

```
Person author = new Person("foo", 100d);
```

Then you can change the `Book` class as follow:

```
public class Book {

    private Person author;
    private String title;

    public Book(Person author, final String title) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

And finally initialize the `Book` object as follows:

```
Person author = new Person("foo", 100d);
Book b = new Book(author, "My Title");
```

Comment: @Pshemo Totally missed that. I should get my morning coffee! :)

Answer (score 1):

> So basically it should get author's name from Person's constructor?

Not necessarily. You can keep the client code simple by creating the Person directly in the Book constructor.

```
public class Book {

    private Person author;
    private String title;

    public Book(String authorName, double height, String title) {
        this.author = new Person(authorName, height);
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

You would call it :

```
Book book = new Book("author", 170, "book title");
```

Yon can also accept a `Person` as parameter in the constructor :

```
public Book(Person author, String title) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
}
```

And in this case, the client code should pass a `Person` and not a `String` and a `double`.

```
Person author = new Person("author", 170)
Book book = new Book(author, "book title");
```

You can even propose both by overloading the constructor.
In fact, the way that you should use is the way that is the most practical for the class clients.

Answer (score 0):

`author` should be a new `Person`, whose name is drawn from the `name` field of `Book`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can solve this:

- By changing the parameter type on your constructor to Person:

  ```
  public class Book {

      private Person author;
      private String title;

      public Raamat(Person author, String title) {
          this.author = author;
          this.title = title;
      }
  }
  ```

  - By initializing the author on the constructor:

    ```
    public class Book {

        private Person author;
        private String title;

        public Raamat(String author, String title) {
            this.author = new Person(author);
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
    ```